# How to tell the direction of travel on Android?

Tags: java, android, gps, location, direction

I have a simple question that I cannot answer. How can you tell the direction of travel, ie. Northbound, Southbound, NE Bound, etc. depending on the direction your Android device moves? I've been trying to use the SensorManager as well as the Accelerometer, but it's terribly inaccurate.

Is there another way for me to implement this feature using those two things? Or is there a better way overall for this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

use GPS and nothing else.

if location.getSpeed() is over 10km/h just take the location.getBearing() (some APis call that getHeading())

Then you have a value in degrees 0-359 where 0 = North, 90° is east.

If the speed is lower than 10km/h it gets more complicated, because bearing would not be acurate.

To convert the degrees values to compass rose N,NE,E,SE,S,SW,W,NW is simple fun, and left to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've implemented what you suggested, and since I'm doing it in meters/second, i converted 10km/h -> m/sec which is around 2.8 m/sec. However, I am having an issue with getBearing() always returning 0 no matter what. I've set my LocationManager to GPS_PROVIDER with 500 ms interval and 5 min distance. The speed is always changing no matter if the phone is staying still. So I'm not exactly sure why getBearing() always returns 0. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why bearing returns 0, but search for that topic or ask a separate question. I am not sure what 5min distance menas